# Javascript function with same name

Tags: javascript

I want o use function with same name in js, basically there is one link:

```
<a onClick="showjury1();" >show</a>
```

when the user is on desktop I want this code to be executed:

```
if (window.screen.width >= 1150) {
  function showjury1() {
    document.getElementById("jury1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("juryline1").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

and when the user is on mobile or at any other resolution I want this code to be executed:

```
if (window.screen.width <= 500) {
  function showjury1() {
    document.getElementById("jury1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("juryline1").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Is this possible? I have executed it and it gives errors; jury1 is not defined etc.

Comment: What are the exact errors?

Comment: why not add the screen width condition inside the function body?that way you can have single function

Comment: it gives errors like showjury1, jury1, juryline1 are not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to define that function twice?  Just use your conditional statement correctly

```
function showjury1()
{
    if(window.screen.width >= 1150)
    {
         document.getElementById("jury1").style.display = "block";
         document.getElementById("juryline1").style.display = "none";
    }
    else if(window.screen.width <= 500)
    {
        document.getElementById("jury1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("juryline1").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
       // might want to do something here too
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working on desktop but when i press ctrl+shft+m it gives errors which means it is not executing the code after else if(window.screen.width <= 500)

Comment: It wont magically execute again if you change screen size. You are calling it only on button click. So after changing the screen size you might want to click the link again

Comment: did you click the button after changing the window size?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
if(window.screen.width >= 1150){
  window.showjury1 = function(){
    ...
  }
}else{
  window.showjury1 = function(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the condition into the function, then you don't need to define the same function twice, because that isn't possible the way you want it to be.

```
function showjury1 {
if(window.screen.width >= 1150)
{
     document.getElementById("jury1").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("juryline1").style.display = "none";
}
else if(window.screen.width <= 500)
{
    document.getElementById("jury1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("juryline1").style.display = "block";`
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining your `showjury1` function inside your `if` statements, put your `if` statements inside your `showjury1` function.

```
showjury1(){
    if(check window width){...}
    else if(check different width){....}
}
```

and make sure your html is loaded before your Javascript otherwise you will get a undefined error when you try to click your button that calls your function.